# pass JSON in GSP page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, grails, gsp

I'm trying to pass JSON data to GSP page and display table.

Expected JSON:

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      "Tiger Nixon",
      "System Architect",
      "Edinburgh"
    ]
]}
```

I'm trying to make it with:

```
def resp = [data:["System", "One", "Test"]]

[resp: resp]
```

and display:

```
<g:javascript>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable( {
     "ajax": "${raw(resp)}"
  } ); } ); 
</g:javascript>
```

But result in page source code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "\u007bdata=\u005bSystem\u002c One\u002c Test\u005d\u007d"
    } );
```

How to pass it correctly?

UPD1:

When I pass a string it works:

View:

```
 <g:javascript>
        var str = '${raw(resp)}';
        var json = JSON.parse(str);
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
           data: json
        } );
    } );
    </g:javascript>
```

Controller:

```
def resp = '[[ \"Tiger Nixon\", \"System Architect\", \"Edinburgh\"]]'    
respond resp, model:[resp: resp]
```

Page Source code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var str = '[[ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh"]]';
    var json = JSON.parse(str);
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
       data: json
    } );
} );
```

But when I try to pass

```
def resp = [["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh"]]
```

it generates an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst you have got it to work, I think maybe you are manipulating your data into non standard methods to get a result in a round about way.

I will try and explain an alternative way and a way which can be used within your service to build the map you are sending which then just rendered in controller:

> def resp = [data:["System", "One", "Test"]]

What you have there is:

```
//A groovy map object
Map resp = [:]
//It has one element called data which contains a list
resp.data=[]
//add in system
resp.data << 'system'
resp.data << 'One'
resp.data << 'Test'
```

This may have been a list generated by some findBy or other form of db lookup in which case resp.data just becomes the list

```
def myList=['system','one','Test']
resp.data=myList
```

Now we have back our object as you had it

```
def resp = [data:["System", "One", "Test"]]
or 
Map resp = [data:["System", "One", "Test"]]
```

If you now do

```
String myResp = (resp as JSON).toString()
```

You are using groov as JSON to first convert that map to json and finally convert the JSON object into string

You could have a function in a service that returns either the JSON or finished String object to the controller directly building data dynamically.

I have only given my two cents because looking at:

```
def obj = [["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh"]]
```

Seems like some odd map you are building just to match your [java script which I think could possibly do with improvement](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-boselecta-plugin/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=JSON.parse) to work directly with the given map rather than this strange object:

```
<g:javascript>
    var str = '${raw(resp)}';
     var jsonData = JSON.parse(str);
var jsonResult = jsonData.data;
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
       data: jsonResult
    } );
} );
</g:javascript>
```

I think now `jsonResult` will just hold the object you were looking at. I provided a link to improving javascript to a search result from within one of my plugins. I did some json stuff with that and wschat plugins.

Haven't tested any of above just going on what how I did it vs your style which looks unusual and possible non comforming to any standards and a harder way to go about building larger dynamic data sets

Answer (score 0):

```
[resp: resp]
```

change to:

```
[resp: resp as JSON]
```

Comment: do you mean [resp: resp as JSON]? Because only "resp as JSON" returns empty page instead of my View

Comment: yup. I forgot it's monolithic.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: 
Controller:

```
def obj = [["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh"]] 
String resp = obj.encodeAsJSON();
respond resp, model:[resp: resp]
```

encodeAsJSON() generates right output in ""

View:

```
<g:javascript>
    var str = '${raw(resp)}';
     var json = JSON.parse(str);

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
       data: json
    } );
} );
</g:javascript>
```